# How to export zone file in whm / webhost

Tags: centos

Someone wants the zone files , registry keys for the domain name.
I don't know how i can get all that information
Can anyone guide me the command to execute to get that

centOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

zone files are moved via a Zone Transfer; this is accomplished in different ways depending on whether you're hosting your own zone in your own DNS server or whether you're just talking about sending the DNS records in place to someone (I'm guessing it's the latter).

Not sure what you mean by "registry keys" -- are you just wanting to transfer a domain to another registrar?  You need to make sure it's not locked and you'll likely need to get/provide the EPP key to authorize the transfer.

As for WHM on a shared host (like Host Gator), the best you can do is "Edit DNS Zone" and then CTRL-A/CTRL-C and paste it in a text file and email it to them I guess; there's no real export function.

Answer (score 1):

In cPanel/WHM backups you can find the zone files in the `dnszones` directory.

Answer (score 1):

Just an addition, the DNS zone files are placed in `/var/named` directory and its configuration file is placed in `/etc` with the name `named.conf`, so you need to download the following:

```
/var/named # Directory containgin zone files
/etc/named.conf # Configuration file of Nameservice
```

You must have `root` Access of your server through SSH.