# How can I effectively slave a couple of DNS zones hosted by HostGator? Does anyone have a script?

Tags: domain-name-system

Similar to the question asked here: [How to export zone file in whm / webhost](https://serverfault.com/questions/130756/how-to-export-zone-file-in-whm-webhost), I was looking for a way to AXFR zonefiles and was told by the hostgator staff that they will not enable it.

They offered to copy over the particular zonefiles I need to distribute to slaves, but that's a one time static thing and I actually needed to update slave servers that I'm running with this data as it occasionally changes. So that didn't really help me.

Since the zones in question are under one of their 'shared hosting' plans, allowing zone transfers - even to specific IP addresses is out of the question.

Is there a script out there I can use to farm the two zones I need to have from hostgator on a regular basis?

I looked at http://network-tools.com/default.asp?prog=dnsrec&host=SLD.TLD but that only provided a couple of A and NS RRs, I need all of the A, NS, TXT, and MX RRs. I don't need SOA RRs since I'm just going to create other master zones on another server that I can actually slave from.

Comment: So are you looking to build new masters and make those authoritative, or slave off of their servers that you can't transfer from?  Having it both ways would be.. messy..  As far as farming the zones without a transfer, you'd need to brute force the names (or tell the script which names to harvest).

Comment: I Agree with devicenull - Why you need hostgator zones at all ? Just host your DNS elsewhere and use hostgator only for webhosting/mail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need some type of script that was specific to your host in order to do this.  You could probably screen-scrape their web interface for modifying records, though this seems fragile.  I'd suggest that you are looking at this the wrong way.  Why do you want/need to do this?  Perhaps your DNS needs would be better served by a company that does DNS hosting only?